# "unsupported matrix index in replacement" when partly assign values to a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to change some values in a dataframe. In this case, the negative value is mutiplied by "-0.5". I can use the following `for` and `if` loop to attain it, though not tidy.

```
name  <- c("a", "b", "c")
value <- c(-10, 3,6)
df    <- data.frame(name, value)
for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$value[n] < 0) {
    df$value[n] <-df$value[n] * (-0.5)
  }
}
```

I tried this way:

```
df[df[2] < 0] <- df[2] * (-0.5)
```

But an error occurs, which said:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df[2] < 0, value = list(value = c(-2.5,  : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: careful with how you access positions. Try `df[df[,2]<0,2]=df[df[,2]<0,2]*-0.5`

Comment: df[df[2] < 0] <- df[2] * (-0.5); your leftside df and your rightside df might not be of the same size. try dim(df[df[2] < 0] and dim(df[2] * (-0.5))

Comment: When you want to update a subset in R, just subset by condition and update- no need in loops. In your case it could be `df$value[df$value < 0] <- df$value[df$value < 0] * -.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest multiplying all rows, but for positive ones use `1` (multiplication by `1` won't change anything). For example:

```
# Return -0.5 for negative values and 1 for positive
df$value * ifelse(df$value < 0, -0.5, 1)
# [1] 5 3 6
```